# Pegar valor de EditText de um layout passado como parâmetro para um AlertDialog.Builder ao clique do botão?

Tags: java, android

Utilizo LayoutInflater na minha view - `View view = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog, null);` Criei um AlertDialog.Builder builder setando para ele a view, e os botões positivo e negativo. O meu Layout tem um EditText e quero pegar o valor do EditText após o clique do botão positivo. Eu utilizo uma variável do tipo EditText para resgatar a referência do EditText do Layout com o R.id.edtText, mesmo assim, utilizando o log o valor dele é null. Como faço pra conseguir pegar o valor do EditText neste caso?

```
LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Criando novo arquivo de apresentação");
    builder.setView(view);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Criar",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    nomeArquivo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomeArquivo);
                    String temp = diretorio + nomeArquivo.getText().toString() + ".cron";
```

Essa parte do código dá um erro e finaliza minha aplicação. - `nomeArquivo.getText().toString()`

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/arquivoicon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Nome do arquivo:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nomeArquivo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="teste" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você eatá a utilizar o `findViewById` da `Activity`.

Você tem de utilizar o `findViewById` do AlertDialog: `dialog.findViewById(R.id.nomeArquivo);`

```
LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();

    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Criando novo arquivo de apresentação");
    builder.setView(view);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Criar",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    nomeArquivo = (EditText) ((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.nomeArquivo);
                    String temp = diretorio + nomeArquivo.getText().toString() + ".cron";
```

Comment: ramaral funcionou perfeitamente, só tive que fazer uma alteração. - nomeArquivo = (EditText) ((Dialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.nomeArquivo); - tem um ponto(.) entre o parênteses e o findViewBy... Obrigado!