# Trabalhar com layout customizado de um alertdialog

Tags: android, kotlin

Criei este layout, para poder trabalhar com este alertdialog.  O criei, pois tenho que gravar os estados após o clique e também, ao abrir o dialog, eu conseguir pegar o valor que foi marcado anteriormente. O buscar através do preferences.

Mas, mesmo trazendo a activity, não consigo buscar seus ID's, obviamente, pelo motivo deles não estarem no layout da activity.

Então, como posso trabalhar com este layout criado para fazer o que deve ser feito?

Code:

```
R.layout.alertdialog_radiobutton_account >> my layout
```

Function:

```
fun onWhoCanContactMeClicked(activity : Activity) {

val dialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
dialog.setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.whocancontact_settings))
        .setView(R.layout.alertdialog_radiobutton_account)
        .setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.ok_dialog)) { p0, p1 ->
            //TODO After click set state
        }
        .setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.cancel_dialog)) { p0, p1 ->
            p0.dismiss() //dismiss dialog
        }
        .create()
        .show()
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.plugapps.zuk.viewmodel.AccountViewModelKotlin">

        </variable>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rdg_dialog_account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_large"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdb1_contact"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@string/everyone_dialog"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdb2_contact"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@string/onlymycontacts_whocancontact_settings"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdb3_contact"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@string/my_contacts"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Imagem do layout:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit**

As respostas me fizeram sair do lugar, vou deixar exatamente como construi o código aqui:

```
fun onWhoCanContactMeClicked(activity: Activity) {

    val li: LayoutInflater = activity.layoutInflater
    val view: View = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_radiobutton_account, null)

    var rgb1: RadioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.rdg_dialog_account)
    var rdb0: RadioButton = view.findViewById(R.id.rdb1_contact)
    var rdb1: RadioButton = view.findViewById(R.id.rdb2_contact)
    var rdb2: RadioButton = view.findViewById(R.id.rdb3_contact)

    when (whoCanContactMe) { //esta variável é um Int
        1 -> rgb1.check(rdb1.id)
        2 -> rgb1.check(rdb2.id)
        else -> rgb1.check(rdb0.id)
    }

    val dialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    dialog.setTitle(activity.getString(R.string.whocancontact_settings))
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.ok_dialog)) { dialog, wich ->
                whoCanContactMe = when {
                    rdb1.isChecked -> 1
                    rdb2.isChecked -> 2
                    else -> 0
                }
            }
            .setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.cancel_dialog)) { p0, p1 ->
                p0.dismiss() //dismiss dialog
            }
            .create()
            .show()
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4682/2541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
final LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

 View view = li.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog_numero_trasferir, null);

 final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_dlg_numero);

 view.findViewById(R.id.btn_dlg_ok).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {


                        numero = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());


                        MainActivity.alerta.dismiss();

                }
            });

            view.findViewById(R.id.btn_dlg_cancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    MainActivity.alerta.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.lbl_titulo_transferencia));
            builder.setView(view);
            alerta = builder.create();
            alerta.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que quer obter referências às views do layout do dialog quando é clicado um dos botões.

O valor passado ao primeiro parâmetro do método `onClick` de DialogInterface.OnClickListener, neste caso identificado como `p0`, é um DialogInterface.

Através dele é possível aceder às views usando

```
((Dialog) p0).findViewById(R.id.nomeDaView);
```

Aconselho a alterar os nomes dos parâmetros `p0` e `p1` para `dialog` e `which`, para melhor entendimento do que representam.

Comment: Obrigado! as variáveis são as que o kotlin gera. Vc diz que, devo ter um case(when) para ver qual tem o check ao clicar no botão positivo? Estou correto? E, minha pergunta gira, também, em torno tb, do layout ser inflado com um valo pre determinado, vindo da sharedpreferences, por exemplo

Comment: *"Vc diz que, devo ter um case(when) para ver qual tem o check ao clicar no botão positivo?"* - Não, na resposta não me refiro a isso. Em relação à segunda parte, não tinha entendido que pretendia pré preencher as views do dialog,

Comment: Eu fiz um edit no post. Perguntei pois, tenho 3 radiobuttons, e precisava setar o valor do que estiver selecionado.

Comment: Sim, só depois de ver a edição é que entendi o que pretendia.